# Hide Url Show only Domain

Tags: html, .htaccess

How do I hide the full url path from one folder with html documents in it?

I did google this subject and did not found a working solution
i tried understanding the appache help files to re-write rules but it did not make sense to this newby
there are many links i found about url masking, but this is not what i need, i found many links about url beautifier, but thats also not what i need...

i like to hide the whole path in my url, and do not know if its possible with htaccess, or how to do it in a different way

i tried loading a iFrame into my page because that would hide my url path as well, but since i use mainly JavaScript, i did not find a solution to get from php a possibility to run a JavaScript function that adds an iFrame to my site.

i do have a php mail file when complete it opens a new thank-you html document
then the path and file name is visible of this document, that i want to learn how to hide

current url:

```
www.example.com/includes/html/thank-you.html
```

prefrered url:

```
www.example.com
```

Comment: did do research, my answer is not found by research, nor was it explained in the link you showed me

Comment: i did, and there it is about an php file that wants to hide one directory, if i understand correct, i like to hide the whole url, always, from all html files in one directory, always having a clean url with only domain visible, that is not being answered in the link you provided, i looked at many forums already, i tried understanding the apache rewrite help documentation but did not understand the answers

Comment: Ok, I reopen this and you show what you tried

Comment: i tried almost anything i found on the net jesterday, it took me one day, with my limited newby knowledge, so after one day fiddling i think its ok to ask a question at the professional/forum

Comment: It is, but not without explaining in details - that means usecase and efforts. If we cannot give you an answer you will understand and are able to implement, then it is perhaps better to find a developer that can?

Comment: i tried and googled so often, that even googled tought i was a bot and had to do picture veryfication before i got my google results....

Comment: Lol.. Sorry to hear it.

Comment: NOOO. Update the QUESTION!

Comment: What you are trying to do is simply not possible, sorry.

Comment: NP, hehe... i'm just a newby, and am building a new website, i have done some udemy tutorials, and now working on a new website... i like to learn, and like to get rid of those silly urls, but dont know how, all my future html documents that will be loaded are being stored in that path.

Comment: You could do some bizarre thing like use session variables to track progress through a visit and adjust the content accordingly, but there are many many reasons why you should not. For one, if someone wants to share your content, there will not be any direct links to use.

Comment: Imagine your parents had two dozen kids, and had named all of them Shakena. How would they call just one of you now, specifically & individually, and not all of you at the same time? Does seem rather impossible? Now think what that means for your expressed desire here, to reach all of the pages of your site by just the URL `www.example.com` …

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the complete URL to a resource.

You can make `http://example.com/` be the complete URL to a resource (the easiest way to do that is to call it `index.html` and put it in the `DocumentRoot` directory)), but then `http://example.com/` is the complete URL to **that** resource and **only** that resource.

You can't have two (or more) different documents both at the URL `http://example.com/`.

---

What you are asking for is akin to taking all the house numbers off every house in a street.

Nobody would be able to visit you because nobody could tell which of the 50 hours in the street is the one they want.

Comment: thank you for the clarify, then i think i need to focus on php running a JavaScript command and add a iFrame to my document, or is this also not how its done... my main goal is to get rid of the url, while showing something else... like a thank you, i probably do what i am doing completely wrong

Comment: i tried to get the folders out the link, and the file extension, but did not got that to work either... seems i have to think of a whole new aproach to my project, last time i paid a company over 2000 euro but the website did not work... thats why i am learning it myself